# Non sinusoide to sinusoide

Tags: inverter

My inverter 12 to 220 v  3000w
Should drive my deepwell pump 700w condensator 13 mf
2 x120ah Batteries are full and loading 
Pump motor works  properly on the 220v 50hrz from the net, but with the invertor ,motor does not rotate smoothly at all.
Someone suggested a low pass filter .( What is that)?
What is happening ?and how can i resolve this problem.?
Willem.

Comment: Your inverter probably outputs a square wave, instead of the sine wave. You can't do much.

Answer (score 0):

A 3 kW inverter with a true sine wave output is very expensive.  One alternative is a "modified sine wave" inverter.  You might already have one, but we don't know because you have not told us the maker and model number, or posted a datasheet.

A square wave has many harmonic frequencies, while a sine wave has only the fundamental frequency.  A low pass filter can remove some of the harmonic energy, making the resulting wave more similar to a sine wave.  However, at your voltage and current levels the filter components will be very large and get hot.

The first step is to look at what you have now. Where are you located?